# Meteor 1.0.3.1 + bower - not loading anything but bootstrap?

Tags: meteor, bower

I've posted this Q on the github issues board for meteor-bower, but thought you guys might have uncovered the answer already.

I'm trying to make bower play nicely with Meteor 1.0.3.1.

The `mquandalle:bower` package is installed.

My **bower.json** in the project root:

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "2.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.2",
    "fancybox": "2.1.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "xx",
  "authors": [
    "Lee Benson <lee@leebenson.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Whatever",
  "moduleType": [
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "NA",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    ".meteor/local/bower",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Plus **.bowerrc**:

```
{
  "directory" : ".meteor/local/bower"
}
```

Yet a view-source of the page dump only shows (amongst the non-bower stuff):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mquandalle_bower.js?6f5e05d255022e01686a1080478129b4d5ce7df2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js?f8752e9ae24daec0a0baffd7819122f8c6fd9103"></script>
```

Any idea what happened to fancybox and modernizr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps a bit further, try putting your required files under `main`:
[issue #50](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower/issues/50) or adding an `overrides` section to your app's `bower.json`: [issue #54](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower/issues/54)

> by default **meteor-bower** automatically includes **only the files listed in the main
>   section** of package's bower.json file. The other files will still
>   present in their corresponding folder but not referenced anywhere in
>   your app. (checkout the spec)
>
> If you have a package without a main section, you should manually
>   reference the files you need.

[image]

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the issue. Too many bower packages without a main section! Sort of renders the benefits of this package moot. I've opted for `meteor-external-file-loader` instead and a manual bower build, to explicitly define what's required.

Comment: Scratch that, `miro:preloader`!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the "manual" way with these simple and full controllable steps for your bower elements?

1. cd into your meteor root direcotory
2. bower init (fill out the desired info in the console prompt)
3. touch .bowerrc
4. edit .bowerrc with your favorite editor and specify (as an example):

> {   "directory" : "public/bower_components" }

5. add your packages:

   bower install --save bootstrap

   bower install --save modernizr

   bower install --save fancybox
6. add needed css / js link to your `head` section
7. to update your bower components later just type: bower update

Comment: That's plan B. The benefit to mquandalle:bower is that it handles bundling, minification and concat with no extra build steps. Extra head tags = more http requests.